# How can we update calendar event for Google internet calendar in Outlook 2013?

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2013, google-calendar

I have shared Google calendars and have them imported as internet calendars into my Outlook 2013 as [guided here](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Transfer-calendars-between-Outlook-and-Google-Calendar-3a133146-a30f-45a2-8cf6-701e5962df59).

I have problem with 2-way syncing between the two calendars

1. `Google Calendar -> Outlook 2013` Sync is OK
2. `Outlook 2013 -> Google Calendar` Sync is NOT OK

@2 I have the error saying somthing `public folder` that not allows me to make updates.

What can I do to be able to update such Google Calendar's event?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Even Private URL from Google Calendars comes in as Read Only into Outlook client. My recommendation is to use Android or iOS for full edit of ActiveSync and Google Calendar. Don't do it from Outlook client, it will create a mess because Outlook does not fully support iCal & CalDAV API.